# convert from String to List<String> and pass to method in one line

Tags: c#, string

It may be a little unnecessary, but I am looking for a way in C# to convert a String to a List< String > and pass it to a function all in one shot.

Let's say I have a function that takes a list of Strings and spits them out to the console.

```
public static void PrintStrings( List<String> messages )
{
   foreach ( String message in messages )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( message );
   }
   //Do other things
}
```

Now assume there is a case where I want to have only one String passed into the function.  This is my question: How can I call this method passing only one String without putting it into a list beforehand?  I thought this would have worked:

```
PrintStrings( Convert.ToString( "mymessage" ).ToList() );
```

But it is flagged in Visual Studio as 'The best overloaded match for 'PrintStrings' has some invalid arguments.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Lots of answers assuming you are open to modifying the existing PrintStrings method or creating overloaded methods. May want to provide clairification.

Comment: You get the compile error because "foo".ToList() yields List<char>

Comment: Not opposed to modifying the PrintStrings method.  Looking for answer that is the smallest, and would preferably just allow me to pass strings directly.

Comment: Then you prob. want to take the approach suggested by dlev, that is use a params argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `params` keyword to allow a variable number of arguments:

```
public static void PrintStrings(params string[] messages )
{
   foreach ( String message in messages )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( message );
   }
   //Do other things
}
```

Now, you can pass either an array of `string`s, a single `string`, or even multiple `string`s:

```
PrintStrings("hi");
PrintStrings("hi", "there");
PrintStrings(stringList.ToArray());
```

Note that this does become less efficient if you already have the `List<string>`. The best way to get around that, though, is to just create an overload that accepts a single `string` and operate on it accordingly:

```
public static void PrintStrings(string myString) { ... }
```

Finally, if you want to keep your current signature and not add an overload, you can call the method on a new `List<string>` like so:

```
PrintStrings(new List<string>() { myString });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `PrintStrings (new List<String>(new string[]{"String"}));`

Or create an overload of PrintStrings that accepts a single string.

Btw, I think it's better to accept `IEnumerable<String>` rather then `List<String>`

Answer (score 1):

You could just create an overloaded method:

```
public static void PrintStrings( string message )
{      
   //Do other things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintStrings( new List<String>() {"myMessage"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintStrings( (new string[] { "myMessage" }).ToList() );
```

edit  - or maybe do an overload ie:

```
PrintStrings( "myMessage"  );

public static void PrintStrings( string message )
{
    AcutallyDoSomething( message );
}
public static void PrintStrings( List<String> messages )
{
   foreach ( String message in messages )
   {
      AcutallyDoSomething( message );
   }
   //Do other things
}

private static void AcutallyDoSomething(string msg)
{
   foreach ( String message in messages )
   {
      Console.WriteLine( message );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintStrings(new List<string>() { "mystring" })
```